# Is using url.openConnection() function safe in java?

Tags: java, security, httpurlconnection

I have a shortened URL. Now I am using HttpUrlConnection to open the connection with the shortened link.

```
URL url = new URL(myshortened url);
```

Now I open the connection by calling:

```
HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = url.openConnection();
```

Finally I am extracting the location header containing the actual destination URL by calling:

```
String expandedurl = httpurlconnection.getHeaderField("Location");
```

At the end I disconnect the `httpurlconnection` by calling:

```
httpurlconnection.disconnect();
```

I want to know if the URL I have used is of a malicious website, can it cause any harm to the calling host? If yes, then what are the possible ways it can attack the calling host?

**Edit:** I have even disabled redirect by calling:

```
httpurlconnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

Comment: You are aware that this code doesn't actually compile?

Comment: Yes, I am not asking what's wrong with code. I know some mistakes are there but my focus is on security.

Comment: Unless you provide code that compiles and exhibits the problem you are asking about, you are in violation of the rules here. NB There is no 'browser redirect' here. Your client is not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with the result. For example if you use it to query a database, it could be vulnerable for [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: I am not doing anything. I am just extracting the expanded url with only the lines of code mentioned above. nothing else. Does even this make me prone to attack? I am not even using getInpuStream or getOutputStream.

Comment: Then your code makes no sense at all. Why even downvite?